# Does azure durable functions always require yield when calling activities?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a problem where i have been working with durable functions and my fuction app resources are drained, usually as i understand it, durable function activities when executed with yield are executed in ansynchronous or parallel mode, so in this example F1 and F2 all called at the same time and when both results are created they will be aggregated here in my list and the whole orchestration will be done, is it possible to execute functions without yield and in sequential order?

---

```
import logging
import json

import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df


def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    result1 = yield context.call_activity('F1', 'arg')
    result2 = yield context.call_activity('F2', 'arg')
    return [result1, result2]

main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

Comment: If you remove `yield` keyword, does your orchestration work[ calling activity F1 and then F2] ?

Comment: What do you mean with "F1 and F2 all called at the same time". From the example, they are not executed in parallel but sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the orchestrator function which is also known as generator function so it has to use Yield Keyword.  There is no way to execute the function without the Yield keyword. In your case, to execute function sequential order you can use function chaining by which we can execute functions one by one.

for further details, you can check the related links

1. [Durable Functions Overview - Azure | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=python)
2. [Simple statements — Python 3.10.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-yield_stmt)
3. [Glossary — Python 3.10.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator)